# how the retryRequest method in ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy is called?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a question regarding the `retryRequest` method in `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy`, how this method is called?

We impelement the interface `ServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy`, and override the `retryRequest`, then how this method is called? Do we need to call it explicitly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method gets called for each response message in the request execution pipeline. See [source](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/execchain/ServiceUnavailableRetryExec.java#L88)

Comment: how about if the server side is unreachable, like the server is restarting, then will the response be null?

Comment: HttpClient _never_ returns null response objects. There will be an I/O exception of a sort.